# Fatal error: Class 'NexmoMessage' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, vonage

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib) to implement the Nexmo SMS service on my server.  I required the library using Composer like so:

```
"require" : {
"prawnsalad/nexmo": "dev-master"
}
```

which I found [here](https://packagist.org/packages/prawnsalad/nexmo) and followed the instructions included in the README like so:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use NexmoMessage;
$phone = '123456789';
$sms = new NexmoMessage(NEXMO_KEY, NEXMO_SECRET);//defined in another file
$sms->sendText($phone, 'from', "yo");//$phone is a valid number in actual case
```

However I keep getting the error in the title of this question.  I see that Composer has imported the library successfully and I see the class and constructor for NexmoMessage, yet for some reason this error keeps happening no matter what I do.  I'm not sure if this is due to an issue with the library or with how I'm using Composer.  I've never had an issue with Composer in the past so I'm boggled why this is happening here.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that library states that it supports PSR-4, which means they absolutely MUST use PHP namespaces, but they don't. That last commit 8 months ago https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib/commit/8e422c4f8f43c52acb70ebd5f9e7c6ff81a1f352 broke the autoloading. And nobody noticed up to today.

You can easily tell by looking at the source code: There is no namespace being used.

Your best action now would be to fix this issue and send a pull request! Github allows to edit files in the browser! Second best action would be to create an issue and let the authors know.

Comment: Well, there have been two issues already sent in the last 2 weeks, and I couldn't resist and sent a pull request. Merging it isn't something I could do, though.

Comment: hey sven, thanks for the tip.  so the fix you made just swapped classmap for the psr-4? excuse me for my ignorance, but how do i now get the version with your fix? do i have to wait for someone with write access to merge this?

Comment: Yes, if you want the code from the official source, you'd have to wait for the merge. You can also add my repository as another source and require that "patch-1" branch instead to get it immediately, but be warned: I will delete this branch once it is merged, and I won't add it to packagist as well - so this is a bit risky if you'd rely on it.

Comment: You could add a classmap autoload entry into your own `composer.json`, pointing to the location of these "Nexmo*" classes (like `vendor/prawnsalad/nexmo/src`). This will be evaluated after the files have been downloaded. It won't interfere with any additional repos being present, and won't interfere with the merge. You should however check if this fix is needed when you update, and remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: OK cool. Makes sense. So just to be clear, if I wanted to implement your last suggestion, I'd add something like

    "autoload" : {
     "classmap": ["vendor/", "prawnsalad/", "nexmo/", "src/" ]
 }

Comment: No, not quite so. To use classmap, you have to give the relative path to the folder you have the classes in - unless you put the vendor folder somewhere else, the path from my previous comment must go into one single string - you made your classmap search in four different folders! It will still work because you will scan the whole vendor folder, but it will take more time than necessary and possibly impact performance due to the huge classmap that will get created.

Comment: Alright. Still trying to figure this out so thanks for bearing with me. So just "autoload" : { "classmap": ["vendor/prawnsalad/nexmo/src/"]}?

Comment: You should check that path once again if it is correctly typed, but yes, that's it.

Comment: Great, I checked and it worked perfectly! Thanks for the help. I'll keep an eye out for when they accept your patch or fix otherwise